# IE11 on Windows Server 2012, not supporting common cipher methods?

Tags: ssl, glassfish, internet-explorer-11

We have an web app in Java for GlasFish server, we set cipher to TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 but IE11 wont open a page at all, saying we need to enalbe TLS 1.0, 1.1 and 1.2
These were enabled in Advanced settings but still no luck. Installed Chrome and it opened a page with no problem.
Trying to open the same page using IE11 from Windows 8.1 gave no problem, too.
Tried to disable Enhanced Security for IE on ser

Any hints, please?

Answer (score 1):

Cipher support differs between browsers and operating systems and new ciphers also sometimes get added with patches. To get an overview which ciphers are probably supported by a specific system have a look at [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/clients.html).

In any case it is recommended that you are using a set of secure ciphers to support the variety of systems and that you don't restrict yourself to a single cipher, especially an advanced and TLS 1.2 only cipher like the one you have chosen.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but this should be ok for both ie11 and server 2012. But i cant open a page, what should i modify on server to make it open, please?

Comment: @Alex: "...and that you don't restrict yourself to a single cipher, ..." . So please add multiple ciphers so that you can support a variety of browsers.